# Recommended Linux Distro for Android Development Workstation

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, java

I'm trying to determine which is the best/preferred/recommended linux distribution for native Android development ?

I'm looking into Ubuntu now, but am also considering CentOS (I've always liked RedHat).

I guess at a bear minimum, the OS needs to

1. Support the latest JDK (required by Android SDK)
2. Run Eclipse (which means a Desktop package is required as well, like GNOME or KDE).

At work I develop on windows using mono and visual studio, but now that I got 4.2.2 loaded on my kindle fire,
I really want to start doing some native Android stuff (which will hopefully help my Monodroid debugging skills).

**Update:** Make that a Kindle Fire HD 8.9, since my battery started to expand ever so slightly (I caught it early, it gets worse), pushing away the side trim a few millimeters,  Amazon is sending a upgraded replacement.

Thanks.

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=703320

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Android application development using the SDK, it doesn't really matter. However, if want to create or modify more low-level components in Android, the official recommendation is Ubuntu [[1]](http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html):

```
The Android build is routinely tested in house on recent versions of 
Ubuntu LTS (10.04), but most distributions should have the required 
build tools available. Reports of successes or failures on other 
distributions are welcome.
```

Be aware, that for building the Android system and kernel source for newer Android versions (> 2.3), you will need a 64-bit (amd64) distribution. I compiled the Android source on Ubuntu 13.04 amd64 without a problem.

You **don't** need that for pure application development. Use whatever you prefer.

**References:**

- [How to Configure Ubuntu 13.04 Raring Ringtail for Compiling Android ROMs](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2224142)

Comment: Oh yeah, I totally forgot, somewhere I've seen the OS my android build was built on (and I do recall seeing Ubuntu). Man if that dawned on me I wouldn'tve even posted. Thanks.

Comment: Good tip bout the 64-bit AMD version. That sucks, I have an intel ATOM netbook. Well, I'll be just doing apps for now, guess I'll have to get some new hardware if I get down into the cross-compilation chains and stuff.

Comment: Thats so funny, the whole reason I was reinstalling my netbook was b/c the version of Ubuntu I had on it, Lucid (10.04 LTS) EOL'ed back in May!  I knew I should've stayed on it. Guess I'll just reinstall it (I overwrote it with 12.1, but Unity is wayyy to much).

Answer (score 3):

I would say go with the one the the most support. Right now that would be Ubuntu. Cent OS is for servers. Unless you are also going to be running a server I would not recommend it. Linux Mint is in second place but it is from Ubuntu. So Ubuntu is final answer. the new [android studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) is also supported but an Ubuntu